# Tuning fork in last two episodes of Legion S02

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, legion

In the last two episodes of *Legion*, David sets a big tuning fork called "The Choker" which, when hit, removes the power of telepaths in the area. He is planning to use it against Farouk, who foresees his plan and sends the fork away.

During the fight, though, Lenny discovers the tuning fork is still somehow close enough from the brawl for it to be efficient.

[image]

How come the device was still there? And, even if it is a coincidence, how come Farouk didn't realize he was still in range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Legion* is a series that relies a great deal on supposition and therefor there are several things in the series that have questions that are not answered or are not answered thoroughly. It's apart of *Legion's* surrealist charm in it's quest to subjectively explore the nature of one's reality. In fact most of characters themselves hardly ask any of the right questions and even if they do, they end up following a different train of thought soon there after.

[image: Future-Syd]

Even looking at the bigger picture, Season 2 also introduced this idea that there is an alleged "future" that relates to this particular time line, as a "Future-Syd" time travels back to change the past, as David is going to become the villain who destroys the world...Future-Syd comes with her own set of [mysteries](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2400952/3-legion-details-you-might-have-missed-about-future-syd-and-david) that are never directly answered.

### WARNING: Season 3 Spoilers!

> This whole plot line sets up the main plot for season 3, which is
>  about David finding a time traveler to change the past (in order to
>  change the future), while Division 3, Syd, AI Robotic version of
>  Ptonomy, Cary & Kerri, and Amahl Farouk wage war on David and his
>  followers so this alleged Future-David destroying the world doesn't
>  happen...
>
>  -- The series never get's back to the notion of "Future-Syd" in a direct
>  sense, as it's the past along with "time-eating" demons (*yes, you
>  read that right*) that takes center stage.
>
>
>
>  -- The series ends with the reveal that the time traveler called Switch
>  becomes **a celestial being** in which she tells Sydney that the universe
>  has a purpose for her and that she will have a better future, because
>  of what she (and David) are  doing.The series then ends on a hopeful
>  note, but in fact there is no physical evidence to prove that the
>  future is better for humanity or any known character, as Syd and David
>  end their scene together bittersweet.

### The reason that's important to trying to answer this Question, is because once the notion of time travel is introduced, it makes the audience ask, *If the future is changeable or if there is a predetermined element at play?? Are things happening for a reason or none at all???*

In the season 2 episode Chapter 14, the audience is treated to an episode that shows several alternate realities in which David almost never has a happy adult life and where he becomes a danger to others. Making the audience believe that *a better future* might be impossible with the exception of one reality where he and Syd grow old together. It's not happy per say, because Syd has to care for a debilitated David and there is something mundane, isolating, and super tedious about it, but their love seems more genuine and less contentious than it has ever been shown on the series elsewhere.

But getting back to the tuning fork, we know before the fight David has executed a plan to get everyone and everything he needs, but it is ***never explained how** he is able to work it all out to know what would happen*, up to some point? Obviously there are things he can't predict, like Syd turning on him or getting too caught up with fighting Olivier, but yet he could set everything before that up! And in season 3, he needs another character's help
to change outcomes

> with Division 3, so what happened to this ability or did Division 3
>  just get smarter/better technology???

Still, there is some leeway to speculate that perhaps **everything happens for a reason** on *Legion*, meaning that coincidence is not just coincidence, because of the revaluation,

> of Switch (the time-traveling mutant) and her father in the final
>  episode, gives subtext to a "higher power" that has some greater
>  control or understanding of the universe(s).

Comment: I haven't watched season three yet so I don't know really which part i can read and which I can't  I will read your full answer as soon as I do ! I agree with the first part though.

Comment: @Badda Sorry about that, I can put the whole thing in spoiler tags, if you like? The problem with asking questions about "purpose" (if something a coincidence or not or examining "fate"), is that it sometimes relies on a series' mythology, which might mean you need the whole series to make that determination.

Comment: I would really like it if you could. I realize it wasn't really smart of me, but I felt like it was unlikely that the answer would be somehow explained in the season 3 ! Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: I just wanna say that Legion is one of the best series I have watched, and reaaaally underrated...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel It is! :D But I totally understand why it's not for everyone. It's lack of straight forward story telling can be frustrating for those that don't REALLY like to  think.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a magnet, it's a [tuning fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork).

---

Here is the relevant dialogue from the episode:

> *Cary Loudermilk:* But Clark's coming, too, and he's bringing something.
>
> *David Haller:* The Choke. It's a dampener.
>
> *Cary Loudermilk:* What does it dampen?
>
> *David Haller:* Us. Our powers. **Something to do with the frequency when you ring it. None of our powers work.**
>
> *Cary Loudermilk:* So you
>
> *David Haller:* **When we ring that bell, we're all just men for a few minutes.**

Comment: Thanks for the word, I was searching for it ! I understand why they want to use it, I just dont understand why it was still there after Farouk discovered it and sent it flying